# Insert a digital signature (from a certification in the Strust transaction)

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, abap, sap-smart-forms

I need to insert a digital signature (from a certification in the SAP transaction `STRUST`) into a PDF generated from a smartform

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the scenario you want to describe. It appears to include injecting an existing digital signature into a newly created PDF. If I understood that correctly, then you're most likely out of luck: to digitally sign a pdf, the pdf must already exist and be prepared for signing before the signature can be crested.

Comment: Currently, I have a program that generates a PDF from the Smatform and sends it by mail to the provider.
The objective is to set up the electronic signature of this PDF before it is sent by mail to the suppliers.

I already import the certificate on the STRUST transaction with which I have to sign the generated PDF

Comment: By STRUST you mean [S-TRUST](https://www.s-trust.de/index.htm)? If not, please explain.

Comment: @mkl: STRUST is a name of a transaction in SAP system, which is specified in the question whatsoever. If you do not understand it, it means you had nothing to do with SAP Systems in your career.

Comment: @Jagger Indeed, and I'm not really unhappy about that. ;) (If you wonder why I reacted here: In my career I've very much had to do with integrated PDF signatures.) As no one of the 2.8K [tag:sap] followers here comes forth with an idea, the OP probably should try and re-phrase his question so that people without SAP background but with PDF knowledge can help.

Comment: you should be really happy about that :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not possible, as [note 841850](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/841850) say us. OTF data (which are SmartForm and SapScript) do not support digital signatures.

[Use Adobe Forms](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/21/digital-signature-in-adobe-forms/) instead.